# Why glob is not getting files in subfolders

Tags: python, file, directory

I have following directory structure

```
$ find
.
./file1.html
./soquest_glob.py

./dir1
./dir1/file2.html

./dir2
./dir2/file3.html
```

(I have added blank lines above to clarify files in different folders).

I am trying to find all html files (including those in subfolders) with following Python code using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) package:

```
$ cat soquest_glob.py

import glob
flist = glob.glob("*.html", recursive=True)
print(flist)
```

However, when I run this code, it finds only file in current folder, not in subfolders:

```
$ python3  soquest_glob.py
['file1.html']
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `recursive` argument to [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) effects the behavior of `**`. You need to use a pattern like: `glob.glob("**/*.html", recursive=True)`.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine, it should work.